# Regular Expressions: Is there a term for the set of matches?

Tags: regex, terminology

I'm writing a paper and wonder if there is a term for the set of regex matches.

For example, given a regex and an input such that we get the matches `(foo, bar, foo, baz, bar, foo)`, I'm looking for a term for the set `{foo, bar, baz}`, respectively for its elements.

If I remember correctly, these elements are called *realizations*. But I can't find any references to this on the internet.

Comment: You are certainly talking about language theory, and may have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language

Comment: You're right. Then the set `{foo, bar, baz}` is a subset of the regular _language_ which is defined by the regex, and its elements are _words_. But imho both terms are a bit ambigous in a non-logics context. Btw _realization_ is used in statistics as a term for the observed value of a random variable, while the above-named _words_ are observed values of the regex in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Found your reference :
https://jvolcic.neocities.org/realizations_28june15.pdf
Realization is truely a mathematical term for linear functions, which a rational expression algorithm may be, in some cases.